# haproxy multiple acl using the same name

Tags: haproxy

I am in the middle of writing a new config for HAProxy - What I want to do is this.

```
acl ccbill src 64.38.212.0/24
acl ccbill src 64.38.215.0/24
acl ccbill src 64.38.215.0/24
acl ccbill src 64.38.215.0/24
use_backend admin-chat if ccbill
```

I am just curious if you can set an acl like this using the same name for multiple IP's

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes you can.
HAProxy will process a logical OR between each ACL.

Comment: I just noticed the edit to this... so do I need to put "OR" between each subnet or keep it as I put up top?

Comment: No, you don't - it's assumed.